# Does gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi build for a 64 bit target?

Tags: gcc, arm

The processor I'm building for is 64 bit ARM. Will this tool chain work?

Comment: Semi-duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21556051/how-to-use-aarch64-linux-gnu-objdump-to-disassemble-v7-mode-instructions-a32-t3

Answer (score 5):

The answer is no.

The tool chain you are referencing is old, and works for 32bit architectures.

You need this (ubuntu):
`sudo apt-get install gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu g++-aarch64-linux-gnu`

Answer (score 3):

64-bit ARM support in GCC is separate backend, called AARCH64. So your compiler normally must be called something like gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu-*.

Still, your question is strange, because, if you will rename 64-bit ARM compiler executable to gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi (you may do it, why not), then answer will be yes.

Comment: Weirdly `arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc` has a `-march=armv8-a` option, but the generated output is still 32-bit. Presumably aarch32?