# 64bit ubuntu compiler arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-4.8

Tags: arm, ubuntu-14.04, cross-compiling, apt-get

What is the package name of arm-linux-gnueabihf 64bit gcc compiler under ubuntu to install using apt-get?

I am having amd64 and while i am installing gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf through apt-get, it is installing 32bit compiler. But i want to install 64bit as well. Kindly let me know how to install 64bit compilers?

Comment: Wait, do you mean 64-bit x86 host, 64-bit ARM target, or both?

Comment: Yes, the cross tool chain of 64bit on x86_64 host.

Comment: For 64-bit ARM, the architecture part of the triplet is `aarch64-`, not `arm-`.

Comment: Do you mean  gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21556051/how-to-use-aarch64-linux-gnu-objdump-to-disassemble-v7-mode-instructions-a32-t3 for an overview of the 64-bit/32-bit ARM toolchain relationship.

Comment: Thanks for the information.. really it helped to understand between 32bit Vs 64bit obj